# Can not insert image in table <td> cell

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write a shopping cart for my site and I want to display a table with a row for each item, including the part #, name, quantity, price and a small image. Everything displays fine except for the image, which appears outside (above) the table and not in the cell where I've placed it. Here's the code:

```
//create a table for the items in the cart
 print("<table class='cart_table'>");
 print("<tr class='first_row'>
        <td>&nbsp;Item No.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Item Name&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Quantity&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Price&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Image&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>");
//for each item in the cart
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value) {

    //create a new product object for the item
    $product = new LG_Product($_SESSION['cart'][$i]['item']);
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td>&nbsp;" . $product->itemID . " </td>");
    print("<td>&nbsp;" . $product->productName . " </td>");
    print("<td>&nbsp;" . $_SESSION['cart'][$i++]['qty'] . " </td>");
    print("<td>&nbsp;$" . $product->productPrice . " </td>" );
    print("<td>" . $product->showPrimaryImage('small') . "</td>");
    print("</tr>");
}
//end the table
print("</table>");
```

And here's the function that gets the image:

```
public function showPrimaryImage($variant) {

if($variant == "medium") {
print ("<img style = \" max-width:400px;
max-height:400px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;\"
src=\"" . WEBSITE_URL . PATH_DYNAMIC . "/products_" . $this->productNumber . "_1_" . $variant . ".jpg\"
alt=\"" . $this->productName . "\">
");
}
else if($variant == "large") {
print ("<img style = \" max-width:600px;
max-height:600px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;\"
src=\"". WEBSITE_URL . PATH_DYNAMIC . "/products_" . $this->productNumber . "_1_" . $variant . ".jpg\"
alt=\"" . $this->productName . "\">
");
}
else if($variant == "small") {
print ("<img style = \" max-width:100px;
max-height:100px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;\"
src=\"". WEBSITE_URL . PATH_DYNAMIC . "/products_" . $this->productNumber . "_1_" . $variant . ".jpg\"
alt=\"" . $this->productName . "\">
");
}

}//end function showPrimaryImage()
```

When I view the source in the browser, it appears the code that renders the image is not inside the  pair. When I view the red warning in the browser source, it says:

> start tag "img" seen in "table"

Here's a screen capture of where the image appears:
[image]

And here's the source that's output from my PHP code (when viewed in the browser, the entire  tag statement is in red):

```
    <table class='cart_table'>
    <tr class='first_row'>
        <td>&nbsp;Item No.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Item Name&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Quantity&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Price&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Image&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;BQ2819 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;A WWII Period U.S. Theater-made Fighting Knife with Sheath </td>
        <td>&nbsp;1 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;$270.00 </td>
        <img style = " max-width:100px;
                        max-height:100px;
                        max-height:100px;
                        display: block;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;"
                        src="http://www.mywebsite.com/dynamic/products_2056_1_small.jpg"
                        alt="A WWII Period U.S. Theater-made Fighting Knife with Sheath">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;BQ2819 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;A WWII Period U.S. Theater-made Fighting Knife with Sheath </td>
        <td>&nbsp;1 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;$270.00 </td>
        <img style = " max-width:100px;
                        max-height:100px;
                        display: block;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;"
                        src="http://www.mywebsite.com/dynamic/products_2056_1_small.jpg"
                        alt="A WWII Period U.S. Theater-made Fighting Knife with Sheath">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of print (), can you try echo for the showPrimaryImage() function?

Comment: Please verify if it isn't a typo in the formatted HTML of your output code. The code opens a <td> puts your image opens another <td> and then closes it. If it isn't a typo, then the error is right there

Comment: Yes, it's strange, but you can see the code right there -- there's no reason the image should display outside the last <td></td> pair that I can see, yet it's being rendered outside for some reason.

Comment: @kimbarcelona - I tried it. It does the same thing with either echo or print.

Comment: When I format the code I found the image is not in the `table td` is that you problem

Comment: Might I also suggest using classes instead of your inline style. E.g use  `small` & `large` classes and add the corresponding classes to your style sheet, perahps like `#cart_table img.small {}` & `#cart_table img.large {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the line:

```
print("<td>" . $product->showPrimaryImage('small') . "</td>");
```

You have a string concatenation, which means you will concatenate whatever the return value of the call to `showPrimaryImage` is. However, `showPrimaryImage` doesn't return anything. Therefore the program first outputs the image's html (from the `showPrimaryImage` call) and then outputs `<td></td>` from the outer print.

You need to change print to a return statement for your `showPrimaryImage` function

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct but the image tag actually prints before the `<td></td>` because `showPrimaryImage()` is executed first

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I did not pay enough attention to the output HTML the asker provided and confirmed myself of incorrect logic. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Toby Liu - Thanks! That did the trick! I simply rewrote the function to save the image code to a string and returned it to the calling code. Like this:

else if($variant == "small") {
$imageString = ("<img style = \" max-width:100px;
max-height:100px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;\"
src=\"". WEBSITE_URL . PATH_DYNAMIC . "/products_" . $this->productNumber . "_1_" . $variant . ".jpg\"
alt=\"" . $this->productName . "\">
");
return($imageString);
}

Comment: You took me out from hours of searching for a solution. Thank you very much Toby !

Answer (score -2):

```
function showPrimaryImage($variant) {
  if($variant == "medium") {
    return img;
  } else if() {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. this code may (or may not) solve the problem - but we prefer it if you give some explanation with your code to say what you changed and why it works as a solution. We have heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they can learn a thing or two from your expertise... if only you let them :) Don't forget - what may be a really obvious change to you may not be to them.